# Neural network how to deal with comparison

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm currently working on a DQN network and this question comes to me. As far as I know, neural networks are good at dealing with values that have never seen (generalisation). E.g. If a classification model classifies two samples with the same features except for `feature A`, the first sample has a value of 10.0 and the second sample has a value of 9.9. And they are both classified correctly to `class C`. Then when tested on a similar sample which has its `feature A` value equals 9.85, it is most likely to be classified to `class C` as well.

However, if the comparison is the key to classification/regression. For example, the 'hidden rule' is: if `feature A > feature` B, then `class C`, otherwise `class D`. Since the comparison relation is not known, we cannot feed in the binary comparison result as a feature. Can neural networks still handle this well? Or some particular structure/feature engineering/algorithm can help with this situation.

For example, if `feature B` is equal to 9.88 in the above example, the model has seen samples with `feature A` values of 10.0, 9.9, 9.95, 9.89, and they all fall into `class C`, and another group of samples with `feature A` value of 8.0,9.0,9.7, and they fall into `class D`, then this 9.85 sample come into test. How can the model classify it correctly?

Comment: Learning the relation

$$
\hat{y}_i =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x_1 >x_2$} \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

seems straightforward. The expression $x_1 - x_2$ is linear in $x$, and the coefficients in $w^\top x$ can be estimated in the usual way. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Sycorax Thanks. I am doing reinforcement learning, and I'm expecting the model to outperform simple relationship like you stated, yet I am far behind. So I come up with this question. Looks like my model is having a hard time converging to a 'local optimal' solution as simple as this.

Comment: Both neural networks and RL are hard to use. I have a hunch that the problem is estimating Q/model divergence, since this relation is straightforward.